# std::span why is there no implicit constructor for single objects/instances?

Tags: c++

In my mind it makes a decent amount of sense to be able to implicitly create a `std::span` from singular items, i.e.:

```
int a = 1;
std::span<int> foo = a;
```

as that would allow you for instance to easily pass single objects to functions that expect a `span`, i.e.

```
void foo(std::span<int> items)
{
    //...do something with items
}

int a = 1;
foo(a);
```

In my mind that would make `span` a lot more useful. I am sure there are good reasons why this is not allowed. What are those?

Comment: You can use the (Iterator, count) constructor: `foo({&a, 1})`

Comment: I know I can, but that makes it syntactically rather ugly and verbose for single items. I am specifically wondering why there is no implicit conversion as described above. I want to figure out if this is a deliberate omission and if so, what the reasoning is.

Comment: Write an overload that does `foo({&a, 1})`  for you

Comment: This makes sense if its only one function but not if you want to use span in many places that accept 1 to N instances.

Comment: That could have a disturbing effect on overload resolution in my opinion. Imagine if you wanted to have two different overloads for the function `foo(std::span<int> items)` and `foo(int item)`. If you want a different behavior for the function with one argument(which, in my experience, is not somewhat uncommon), then this could have raised problems.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan that's a good point, this kind of reasoning is what I am looking for, thanks!